# "Fare meglio" nel senso di "essere più salutare"

Tags: word-usage, comparison

Si usa spesso l'espressione "fare bene" in riferimento a qualcosa che è salutare.
Nel caso in cui si voglia fare un paragone del tipo "questo cibo è più salutare di quest'altro", è corretto utilizzare "questo cibo fa meglio di quest'altro"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel caso specifico del cibo non userei dire che uno '*fa meglio*' di un altro, cosa che invece non apparirebbe strana se riferita ad un farmaco.

In ogni caso dire che un cibo 'fa bene' è corretto, ma, come detto sopra, da qui a inferire la possibilità di un confronto fra cibi usando l'accennata terminologia non è consigliabile.

Quindi frasi come, p.e., '... la frutta fa meglio della carne ...' sono inconsistenti, mentre usare '... è più salutare ...' è perfetto.

Comment: Risposta chiara e completa. Grazie :)

Comment: Mi sfugge il fatto che non appare strano usare quel costrutto nel caso di farmaci: "X fa meglio di Y", dove X e Y sono farmaci è una costruzione valida/del tutto comprensibile? A me suonerebbe bislacca.

Comment: @martina Strano, io spesso sento dire 'l'aspirina *fa meglio* del voltaren', anche se io personalmente non lo direi e, semmai, userei 'è più efficace'.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider, quello che uno sente non è necessariamente corretto.

Comment: @bob Non sostengo che sia corretto, ma che 'non apparirebbe strana'.

Comment: Stavo per proporre di completare il "fare bene" con un complemento di termine, ma ora, a furia di pensarci, non riesco piu' a stabilire se  "per il mal di pancia, la camomilla fa meglio della peperonata" suoni naturale o no (e per favore correggetemi se non si tratta di un complemento di termine)

Answer (score 2):

> Si usa spesso l'espressione **"fare bene"** in riferimento a qualcosa
>   che è salutare. Nel caso in cui si voglia fare un paragone del tipo
>   "questo cibo è più salutare di quest'altro", è corretto utilizzare
>   "questo cibo fa meglio di quest'altro"?

Nell'espressione 'fare bene alla salute' 'fare bene' è da considerare un tutt'uno idiomatico = **giova** e sostituisce la espressione ordinaria 'è buono/a per la salute', quindi una sua parte non può essere alterata come se fosse un normale avverbio: 'nel primo trimestre ha fatto bene, nel secondo suo figlio ha fatto meglio'

"fa bene *alla* salute = è buono *per* la salute"

Questa considerazione vale per il cibo, per un farmaco, per lo sport e per tutto.

Volendo fare una comparazione bisogna tornare alla frase di base e qui fare il comparativo di maggioranza; *'+ buono = migliore/meglio'* : "questo alimento/farmaco
[**è meglio**](https://www.google.it/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=%22%C3%A8+meglio+per+la+salute%22&oq=%22%C3%A8+meglio+per+la+salute%22&gs_l=hp.12...2232.14858.0.16907.25.25.0.0.0.0.260.3784.0j23j2.25.0....0...1c.1.54.hp..9.16.2359.0.etDCHFvcTps) per la salute"

Comment: Grazie per la risposta :)